# In Angular 4, can you work with variables in an *ngForOf loop?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to write a template which builds a list where each list entry contains data from the current iterator of a *ngForOf loop, and a bit from the previous iteration of the loop. The way to usually do that type of thing is to store the value of the iterator at the bottom of the loop in a tracking variable so the value is available in the next iteration of the loop. Can you do this type of thing in Angulary 4+? I've tried numerous things which don't seem to work.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Post code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is use the `index` variable, which is one of several special variables you can alias and use inside an `ngFor` (https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf).

```
items = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];

<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  Current item: {{ item }}, 
  previous item: {{ items[i-1] ? items[i-1] : 'No item' }}
</div>

// Output: 
Current item: One, previous item: No item
Current item: Two, previous item: One
Current item: Three, previous item: Two
Current item: Four, previous item: Three
```

Here's an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/iterating-access-previous-item

Comment: Index was it. Thanks. I wrote a function which takes the index and it's array and pulls the previous iteration in the array to piece together what I needed. EX:

   ` <div *ngFor='let dir of (graph | ngForArrayHack); index as j;'>
              <tree-view [graphs]='dir.childrenDir' [parent]='dir.pwdir' [prev]='calcPrev(graph.childrenDir, i)'></tree-view>
    </div>`